# Removing corner radius UIButton

Tags: ios

I have applied a border and a corner radius to a UIButton in this way:

```
self.Button3.layer.borderWidth = 10;
self.Button3.clipsToBounds = NO;
[self.Button3.layer setCornerRadius:100.0f];
```

I wanted to know if there was a way to remove both of them, without doing this:

```
self.Button3.layer.borderWidth = 0;
self.Button3.clipsToBounds = NO;
[self.Button3.layer setCornerRadius:0.0f];
```

I think that this would only hide, not remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is the way to go, since `CALayer` provides no API to "remove" a border other than `borderWidth` property. According to the documentation, `CALayer` just "draws" the border, so, I don't think `CALayer` holds something like an `UIView` or `UIImage` to draw the border.

> When this value is greater than 0.0, the layer **draws** a border using
>   the current borderColor value. The border is drawn inset from the
>   receiver’s bounds by the value specified in this property. It is
>   composited above the receiver’s contents and sublayers and includes
>   the effects of the cornerRadius property.